# JDBC: "SQLException:Column name is not found"

Tags: java, mysql

I have tried to use these two questions as a reference

1. [JAVA - SQLException throws exist column not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729137/java-sqlexception-throws-exist-column-not-found)
2. [Strange SQLException: Column not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672412/strange-sqlexception-column-not-found)

However, none of it helped my case. I keep receiving
`java.sql.SQLException: Column 'debut' not found.`

this is my SQL

```java
private List<MemberModel> getModelFromNickname(String test) throws SQLException {

        List<MemberModel> result = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "select distinct " +
                "m.name," +
                "m.visual," +
                "m.branch, " +
                "m.illustrator, " +
                "m.debut3D AS debut " +
                "FROM " +
                "member_list as m, " +
                "nickname AS n " +
                "WHERE n.nick_id = m.nick AND n.nickname LIKE ?";

        ResultSet ret= sqlAdapter.select(
                sql, 1,test
        );
        while (ret.next()){
            result.add(fillRecord(ret));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

this is my MYSQLAdapter

```java
public ResultSet select(String sql,int option, Object... params) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement query;
        try{
            logger.info(params.length);
            query = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new Error("Problem "+ e);
        }

        resolveParameters(query,option, params);
        return query.executeQuery();

    }
```

this is my fillRecord command

```java
private static MemberModel fillRecord(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        MemberModel member = new MemberModel();
        member.name =resultSet.getString("name");
        member.branch = resultSet.getString("branch");
        member.debut_3d = resultSet.getBoolean("debut");
        member.visual = resultSet.getString("visual");
        member.illustrator = resultSet.getString("illustrator");
        return member;
    }
```

while this is my memberModel

```java
public class MemberModel {
    public String name = "";
    public int social_media = 0;
    public int nick = 0;
    public String branch = "";
    public boolean debut_3d= true;
    public String illustrator ="";
    public String visual = "";

}
```

I tried to use

```java
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = sqlAdapter.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql).getMetaData();
        for(int i =1; i<= rsmd.getColumnCount();i++){
            System.err.println(rsmd.getColumnCount()+"\n"+rsmd.getColumnName(i));
        }
```

which gives me the following (I don't know how it somehow managed to print more than 5. But, all of it except "debut" can be found)

```
5
name
5
visual
5
branch
5
illustrator
5
debut
5
name
5
visual
5
branch
5
illustrator
5
debut
```

This indicates that the debut column should exist yet I still get that exception. Where did I do wrong? I make sure that it is case sensitive just in case. The data type for "debut" column is boolean in my localhost XAMPP MySQL. If I erase `member.debut_3d = resultSet.getBoolean("debut");` within `fillrecord`... Everything works perfectly fine

Comment: Are you sure this is reproducible?  I don't see anything wrong with your actual code.

Comment: I tried it in my XAMPP, and it works perfectly fine. The only part that is problematic for some reason is only for "debut" if I erase that part - The code work perfectly fine as how I want it to be.

Comment: Does it work as is or not?  I don't think what you asked is reproducible, hence my comment above.

Comment: No, it doesn't work as it is giving me this error `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'debut' not found.`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224024/jdbc-resultset-get-columns-with-table-alias

Answer (score 1):

Rather get values by labelName trying column number.

```
private static MemberModel fillRecord(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        MemberModel member = new MemberModel();
        member.name = resultSet.getString(1);
        member.branch = resultSet.getString(3);
        member.debut_3d = resultSet.getBoolean(5);
        member.visual = resultSet.getString(2);
        member.illustrator = resultSet.getString(4);
        return member;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resultSet.getBoolean("debut3D"); // Instead of "debut"
```

The column in the database table is called "debut3D".

BTW you are not closing PreparedStatement and ResultSet. I would use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

The column name is "`debut3D`" not "`debut`", thats why you are getting the error.

Update below line with correct column name,

```
member.debut_3d = resultSet.getBoolean("debut3D");
```